# Do I need to install Bundler manually on my server before being able to deploy with Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, bundler

The title pretty much says it all.

I've just set up my web server with Ruby 1.9.2. It is a clean install -- no gems have been installed yet. Additionally, I've just configured Capistrano for my Rails application.

When I run `cap deploy`, it fails with the following error message:

```
*** [err :: bogusip.com] bash: bundle: command not found
```

Given that all I've done is install Ruby 1.9.2 onto my server, Bundler does not exist at this point. Is Capistrano supposed to install the Bundler gem for me or am I supposed to do that myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes](http://gembundler.com/#using-bundler-with-rails).

Bundler is not included with ruby by default, it is included by rails.  This will be why you have never installed it manually.

Comment: Just to be clear: Capistrano does not install Bundler for you. Correct?

Comment: Correct.  You can see Capistrano's dependencies here: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/capistrano.gemspec

Comment: Thanks! With all the automation going on, I thought this would be one of things Capistrano takes care of, so I just wanted to be sure. =)

Comment: guess you can still add a install_bundle task a la: run "gem install bundle"

Comment: Good idea @Deradon; I'll do that just that. =)