# 1st deploy - need to install all gems on the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy for the 1 time to the server ( cap deploy:cold ) and it keep asking me to install gems.  Just one example:

```
*** [err :: ip-address] Could not find net-ssh-2.3.0 in any of the sources
```

Is there something I could to to install all the gems needed in one shot?

Here is my deploy.rb file, and gemfile:

deploy.rb

```
    set :application, "myapp"
set :repository,  "repo goes here"
set :scm, :git
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`

role :web, "ipaddress"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "ipaddress"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "ipaddress", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
# role :db,  "your slave db-server here"

# if you're still using the script/reaper helper you will need
# these http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts

set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/#{application}"
set :rails_env, 'production'
set :branch, "master"

set :scm, :git
set :user, "user"
set :runner, "user"
# ssh_options[:port] = 2232
set :use_sudo, false
set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false


# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end

namespace :bundler do
  task :create_symlink, :roles => :app do
    shared_dir = File.join(shared_path, 'bundle')
    release_dir = File.join(current_release, '.bundle')
    run("mkdir -p #{shared_dir} && ln -s #{shared_dir} #{release_dir}")
  end

  task :bundle_new_release, :roles => :app do
    bundler.create_symlink
    run "cd #{release_path} && bundle install --without test"
  end

  task :lock, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{current_release} && bundle lock;"
  end

  task :unlock, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{current_release} && bundle unlock;"
  end
end

 after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"

namespace :deploy do

    desc "Restarting mod_rails with restart.txt"
    task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
        run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
    end

    [:start, :stop].each do |t|
        desc "#{t} task is a no-op with mod_rails"
        task t, :roles => :domain do ; end
    end
end

task :after_update_code do  
 run "ln -nfs #{deploy_to}/shared/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
end
```

gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'



gem 'json'
gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'therubyracer'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'
```

Comment: This post might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706485/do-i-need-to-install-bundler-manually-on-my-server-before-being-able-to-deploy-w

Comment: Thanks I saw that - I do have bundler on the machine, but my app isn't deployed yet so I can't bundle install.

Comment: try the answer I added below, I don't see 'bundler/capistrano' included in your deploy.rb file

Comment: verify in your nginx.conf if the passanger_ruby is the same that the capistrano is using.

`whereis ruby` show all available and `which ruby` show the current environment.

Logging with ssh and executing manualy it works?

Comment: whereis ruby
ruby: /usr/local/bin/ruby and /opt/ruby/bin/ruby, then for 
which ruby
/opt/ruby/bin/ruby

Yes, when I manually bundle it installs everything - I added github to gem sources and that helped getting all dependencies installed, but still won't install them via deploy.

Answer (score 1):

maybe if you change this line

```
run "cd #{release_path} && bundle install --without test"
```

to

```
run "cd #{release_path} && bundle install --path=you_gem_path --without #{bundle_without.join(' ')}"
```

you can find your gem path by running

```
$ echo $GEM_PATH
```

you also have to set bundle_without
you can set it in the beginning of file

```
set :bundle_without,      [:development, :test]
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your deploy.rb

```
set :bundle_without, [:development, :test]
require 'bundler/capistrano'
```

Comment: I tried that, but still get :** [out :: ip-address] Could not find net-ssh-2.3.0 in any of the sources

Comment: hmm that's really weird, I thought that would do it. Did you check out this page? http://gembundler.com/deploying.html

Comment: There is this error I just noticed at the bottom: failed: "env PATH=/opt/ruby/bin/:$PATH sh -c 'cd /home/deploy/tomahawk/releases/20120207210055 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile'"

Comment: Try upgrading bundler(if not already this version) to version 1.0.18. That should fix it according to this:https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/81

Comment: Yes I have the latest verions, but I notice it's trying to do this: [err :: ip+address] find: `/home/deploy/myapp/releases/20120208011538/public/images' - there is no images folder in the public directory?